# How to insert multiple data in jsgrid

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

I insert the data using the code below.

```
$("#jsGrid-vws").jsGrid("insertItem",data);
```

However, this method slowed down and the browser went down as the data increased.
I want to know how to put bulk data in the js grid.